# Improving the Performance of Netty Server in JAVA

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, sockets, netty

I have a situation like: My Netty Server will be getting data from a Client at a blazing speed. I think the client is using somewhat PUSH mechanism for that speed. I don't know what exactly PUSH - POP mechanism is, but I do feel that the Client is using some mechanism for sending data at a very high speed.Now my requirement is, I wrote a simple TCP Netty server that receives data from the client and just adds to the BlockingQueue implemented using ArrayBlockingQueue. Now , as Netty is event based, the time taken to accept the data and store it in a queue is some what more , this is raising an exception at the client side that the Netty server is not running.But my server is running perfectly, but the time to accept single data and store it in the queue is more. How can I prevent this? Is there any fastest queue for this situation? I nam using BlockingQueue as another thread will take data from the queue and process it. So I need a synchronized queue. How can I improve the performance of the Server or is there any way to insert data at a very high speed? All I care about is latency. The latency needs to be as low as possible.

My Server code:

```
public class Server implements Runnable {
private final int port;

static String message;
Channel channel;
ChannelFuture channelFuture;
int rcvBuf, sndBuf, lowWaterMark, highWaterMark;

public Server(int port) {
    this.port = port;
    rcvBuf = 2048;
    sndBuf =   2048;
    lowWaterMark = 1024;
    highWaterMark = 2048;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        startServer();

    } catch (Exception ex) {
       System.err.println("Error in  Server : "+ex);
       Logger.error(ex.getMessage());
    }
}

public void startServer()  {
   // System.out.println("8888 Server started");
    EventLoopGroup group = new NioEventLoopGroup();
    try {
        ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap();
        b.group(group)
         .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
         .localAddress(new InetSocketAddress(port))
         .childOption(ChannelOption.SO_RCVBUF, rcvBuf * 2048)
         .childOption(ChannelOption.SO_SNDBUF, sndBuf * 2048)
         .childOption(ChannelOption.WRITE_BUFFER_WATER_MARK, new WriteBufferWaterMark(lowWaterMark * 2048, highWaterMark * 2048))
         .childOption(ChannelOption.TCP_NODELAY, true)

             .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {

                    @Override
                    public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
                        channel = ch;
                        System.err.println("OMS connected : " + ch.localAddress());
                        ch.pipeline().addLast(new ReceiveFromOMSDecoder());
                    }
                });
        channelFuture = b.bind(port).sync();
        this.channel = channelFuture.channel();
        channelFuture.channel().closeFuture().sync();

    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        System.err.println("Exception raised in SendToOMS class"+ex);
    } finally {
        group.shutdownGracefully();
    }
}
```

}

My ServerHandler code:

```
   @Sharable
public class ReceiveFromOMSDecoder extends MessageToMessageDecoder<ByteBuf> {


    private  Charset charset;
    public ReceiveFromOMSDecoder() {
        this(Charset.defaultCharset());
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new instance with the specified character set.
     */
    public ReceiveFromOMSDecoder(Charset charset) {
        if (charset == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("charset");
        }
        this.charset = charset;
    }

    @Override
    protected void decode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf msg, List<Object> out) throws Exception {

       String buffer = msg.toString(charset);
       if(buffer!=null){
        Server.sq.insertStringIntoSendingQueue(buffer);  //inserting into queue
      }
        else{
            Logger.error("Null string received"+buffer);
        }
    }
       @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) {
      //  Logger.error(cause.getMessage());
        System.err.println(cause);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as "Too broad", because you appear to be having multiple problems. One of the problems I pick out of the context is that an exception gets thrown either on the client or server side, and the other problem is your performance problem. The performance problem is also really large on its own, and has many causes. If you expect to receive large amounts of data, you are quickly going to get problems if you leave all your protocol data as strings, and passing every packet directly to your server class also gives its own overhead when looking at the thread contention

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three quickies:

1. Doesn't look like you're sending a response. You probably should.
2. Don't block the IO thread. Use an [EventExecutorGroup](http://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/util/concurrent/EventExecutorGroup.html) to dispatch the  handling of the incoming payload. i.e. something like [ChannelPipeline.addLast(EventExecutorGroup group, String name, ChannelHandler handler)](http://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/channel/ChannelPipeline.html#addLast-io.netty.util.concurrent.EventExecutorGroup-java.lang.String-io.netty.channel.ChannelHandler-).
3. Just don't block in general. Ditch your ArrayBlockingQueue and take a look at [JCTools](http://jctools.github.io/JCTools) or some other implementation to find a non-blocking analog.

Comment: Thank you Nicholas. Currently I am using ConcurrentLinkedQueue instead of ArrayBlockingQueue. I couldn't find any sample examples on JCTools. I am highly confused in using it. I have gone through the library and came to know that SPSC queue is the one for my design. But I don't know how to use it. Can you provide me some examples in using the library or any documentation please

Comment: hema;  I would open a separate question for JCTools inquires.